# Stream response to file using Fetch API and fs.createWriteStream

Tags: javascript, electron, fs, fetch-api

I'm creating an Electron application and I want to stream an image to a file (so basically download it).

I want to use the native Fetch API because the request module would be a big overhead.

But there is no pipe method on the response, so I can't do something like

```
fetch('https://imageurl.jpg')
    .then(response => response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('image.jpg')));
```

So how can I combine `fetch` and `fs.createWriteStream`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE 2023**

Now Node.JS supplies helpers for this very purpose. Check [frank-dspeed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73879265/4262228) for more details.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I got it working. I made a function which transforms the response into a readable stream.

```
const responseToReadable = response => {
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    const rs = new Readable();
    rs._read = async () => {
        const result = await reader.read();
        if(!result.done){
            rs.push(Buffer.from(result.value));
        }else{
            rs.push(null);
            return;
        }
    };
    return rs;
};
```

So with it, I can do

```
fetch('https://imageurl.jpg')
    .then(response => responseToReadable(response).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('image.jpg')));
```

Comment: Careful! This loads the whole content of the file in memory ... Might not be ideal when downloading 2 GB documents ... your might run out of memory.

Comment: @KarstenDaemen can you point out which line of code loads it all into memory? I think that line `const result = await reader.read()` only reads a chunk.

Comment: I'm not sure about your example as I'm no streaming expert and not sure what `rs._read` actually does. Just wanted to add for reference this example using an iterator https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/guest-post/http-streaming-with-nodejs-and-fetch-api/

Comment: for readers of this document while my answer is more correct this answer is also correct and does not read the whole file in memory @James Kerr is correct it reads only a chunk per loop

Answer (score 7):

I guess today the answer is with nodejs 18+

```
node -e 'fetch("https://github.com/stealify").then(response => stream.Readable.fromWeb(response.body).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./github.com_stealify.html")))'
```

in the above example we use the -e flag it tells nodejs to execute our cli code we download the page of a interristing Project here and save it as ./github.com_stealify.html in the current working dir the below code shows the same inside a nodejs .mjs file for convinience

Cli example using CommonJS

```
node -e 'fetch("https://github.com/stealify").then(({body:s}) =>
 stream.Readable.fromWeb(s).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./github.com_stealify.html")))'
```

fetch.cjs

```js
fetch("https://github.com/stealify").then(({body:s}) => 
 require("node:stream").Readable.fromWeb(s)
  .pipe(require("node:fs").createWriteStream("./github.com_stealify.html")));
```

Cli example using ESM

```
node --input-type module -e 'stream.Readable.fromWeb(
 (await fetch("https://github.com/stealify")).body)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./github.com_stealify.html"))'
```

fetch_tla_no_tli.mjs

```js
(await import("node:stream")).Readable.fromWeb(
 (await fetch("https://github.com/stealify")).body).pipe(
  (await import("node:fs")).createWriteStream("./github.com_stealify.html"));
```

fetch.mjs

```js
import stream from 'node:stream';
import fs from 'node:fs';
stream.Readable
  .fromWeb((await fetch("https://github.com/stealify")).body)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./github.com_stealify.html"));
```

see: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromwebreadablestream-options

### Update i would not use this method when dealing with files

this is the correct usage as fs.promises supports all forms of iterators equal to the stream/consumers api

```bash
node -e 'fetch("https://github.com/stealify").then( (res) =>
 fs.promises.writeFile("./github.com_stealify.html", res.body)))'
```

Comment: When I try `stream.Readable.fromWeb(...)` I get the error `The \"readableStream\" argument must be an instance of ReadableStream. Received an instance of PassThrough`, on node 18

Comment: @xaphod then you used the wrong function with the wrong type a passThroug stream is not a web stream so you should not use it with from Web as it is not a Web Stream ....

Comment: I basically copied your code from `fetch.mjs` verbatim and got that error

Comment: @lance It was already fully typed via type inference your version does add nothing i am not sure if this is scam.

Comment: @frank-dspeed I removed it, I originally added it to make it easier to copy/paste for typescript users, but hey.

Comment: @Lance all this examples do work with typescript i am typescript contributor copy any sample and add a //@ts-check above it to see typeinference.

Comment: Oh nice, I never knew about that, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Fetch is not really able to work with nodejs Streams out of the box, because the Stream API in the browser differs from the one nodejs provides, i.e. you can not pipe a browser stream into a nodejs stream or vice versa.

The [electron-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-fetch) module seems to solve that for you. Or you can look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32545850/2016129 to have a way of downloading files without the need of nodeIntegration.

There is also [needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle), a smaller alternative to the bulkier request, which of course supports Streams.

Comment: This is not really true. Have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

Comment: While the browser supports streams, they are not really compatible with the ones of nodejs. You have to use a use some kind of middleware to connect both.