# res.download() download window not showing up

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, http

I created a download button that downloads the file on click. The problem is when I click the download button, I'm able to see the content that I want to download by using `Chrome inspect -> Network -> Response`  but it is not opening a window to save the file to my PC.
For example, I'm trying to download `text.txt` which contains multiple lines of  `MY FILE` string. I'm able to see it on  `Response` tab but how can I download the `.txt` file.[image]

**Relevant React Code:**

```
<button onClick={(e) => downloadHandler(e)}>Download</button>
```

```
    let downloadHandler = (e) =>{
      const fileName = e.target.parentElement.id;
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/download',{
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({id: fileName})
    })
  }
```

**Relevant Backend Code:**

```
const uploadFolder = `${__dirname}` + `\\uploads\\`;
app.post('/download', function(req, res){
    let fileName = req.body.id; // example output: 'dog.jpg'
    res.download(uploadFolder+fileName, fileName); // Set disposition and send it.
  });
```

The idea is that I will feed `fileName` to backend and then download it with `res.download(uploadFolder+fileName, fileName);` line. I think im suppose to use `window.open('/download')` but that just opens the homepage on a new tab or maybe I am just placing it wrong.

Comment: I don't think `fetch()` will pop up the download window. `fetch()` gets data for your Javascript.  I think you'd have to do `res.download()` in response to a browser form post (not done via Javascript) or in response to a URL in the browser bar or a clicked on link.  When you do `fetch()`, the browser is not watching the response.  The response goes to your Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 when you are saying javascript, are you referring to React or Express or both?

Comment: I'm referring to client-side Javascript.  When you make a `fetch()` request in Javascript, you're just getting data for your Javascript, not for the browser.   For the browser to pay attention to the type of response, the response needs to be going into the browser window itself, via things like a typed URL, via a clicked on link or a browser submitted form response.

Comment: @dewren99 Can you please try adding an error handler callback as =>    `res.download(uploadFolder+fileName, fileName, function(err){if (err){console.log(err)} else {res.download(uploadFolder+fileName, fileName);}} `

Comment: @DavidR I am not sure if I understood your request right, but when I replaced my ```res.download``` line with yours, I got this error ```Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.```. But I am still able to see the inside of ```.txt``` file on ```Response``` tab.

Comment: @dewren99 So, are you setting status somewhere after your `res.download..` ? Also are you using `res.end()` after that?

Comment: @DavidR  My react component that stores the ```downloadHandler``` starts like this ```export default function MyDropzone(){...```. I am not saving status after the call and I am not using ```res.end```. The codes posted above are the only parts that are related to the download functionality.

Comment: One final try, Can you please place those two statements, (i.e, `let fileName = ..... and  res.download(uploa.......`) inside an if condition like this, `if (!res.headersSent) { // place those two statements here}` and check if it works?

Comment: @DavidR Unfortunately, It did not affect the output. The same issue persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176982/res-download-not-working-in-my-case

Comment: @arunp9294 I got the idea of ```window.open('download)``` from that post, but I don't know how to apply it in my case. The second comment mentions ``opening a new window with my ajax request location`` but I'm storing files locally, so they are not on a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I have managed to solve my issue. three main modifications were made to make this code and idea work.

1. Changing the request from `POST` to `GET`. [Another
   StackOverflow thread also mentions this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391627/express-res-download)
2. Using `axios()` instead of `fetch()`.
3. Creating `Blob` object from the `res.download(filePath, fileName)` response value.

---

[Anyone else having this problem with the `React Code` part should check this Github link.](https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743)

**Final State of the React function posted in the question**

```
    let downloadHandler = (e) =>{
      const fileName = e.target.parentElement.id;
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:3001/download/'+fileName,
        responseType: 'blob',
        headers: {},
        })
        .then((res) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
        })
  }
```

**Final State of the backend code posted in the question**

```
const uploadFolder = `${__dirname}` + `\\uploads\\`;
app.get('/download/:filename', function(req, res){
    let fileName = req.params.filename
    const filePath = uploadFolder+fileName;
    res.download(filePath, fileName);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that i was navigating to http from https