# How to download file using react js and asp.net core v3.0

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting base64 pdf string from web service then converting the base64 to Byte[] then returning  the file in controller but file is not getting download

I am using react as front calling the controller using fetch api

```js
fetch('/api/PDFDownload/PDFDownloadStat', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getCookies("CSRF-TOKEN")
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => res.json())
       
        }).catch(error =>
        {
            console.log(error)
        });
```

```
public class PDFDownloadController : Controller{    

[HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PDFDownloadStatController(PDFEntity pdfObj)
        {

            var response = string.Empty;
            Byte[] Base64=null;
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {                  
                    Base64 = genPDF.GetPDFByte();  // getting Byte for pdf

                }              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return File(Base64, "application/pdf", "myFile.pdf");
        }
}
```

Comment: Right now you are parsing the response of your request as json, which is (obviously) not going to work for file's. Look into `fetch`'s `response.blob()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob - perhaps in combination with a library such as `downloadjs` to convert that blob into a (downloaded) file: https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs

Comment: Or refer to the answer posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32545850/3061857 to see how you use `response.blob()` with `downloadjs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are download file so you will need add blob response in your code

```
fetch('/api/PDFDownload/PDFDownloadStat', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getCookies("CSRF-TOKEN")
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => return response.blob())
        }).catch(error =>
        {
            console.log(error)
        });
```

In mozilla docs example:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();

var myInit = { method: 'GET',
               headers: myHeaders,
               mode: 'cors',
               cache: 'default' };

var myRequest = new Request('flowers.jpg', myInit);

    fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
      return response.blob();
    }).then(function(myBlob) {
      var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
      myImage.src = objectURL;
    });
```

You can read full code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)