# Interacting with HTML audio object using JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I would like to interact with the vertical ellipses in an HTML DOM Audio Object.  Here is an example audio object: (credit: w3schools, original HTML taken from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_controller)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

I've had success with implementing the pause/play controls, returning the duration of the song and getting the SRC.  Here I create a button that executes myFunction() to click the play button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  x.play();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to do is to click on the vertical ellipses
[image: Audio Ellipses]

then click again to download the song.
[image]

My question is: what is the JavaScript code to click on the vertical ellipses in the audio object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  In fact, the UI of the player is not necessarily standard.  It can vary from platform to platform.

You can use `.src` to get the `src` attribute of the media element and download it yourself via the Fetch API or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I did read that each browser has its own set of default audio controls, so that makes sense.  Could you elaborate a little bit on the Fetch API?  I couldn't find much after some searching.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545632/how-can-i-download-a-file-using-window-fetch) looked promising, but I wasn't able to get anything to work for my case.  It also seemed to focus more on download.js than fetch

Comment: @AlexW I don't know what download.js is, but this specific answer seems pretty clear:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59940621/362536.  Or:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API