# How to Download Pdf File in React From Api

Tags: reactjs, flask

I want to download pdf file by fetching from Flask db.

React code:

```
downloadReport(idx) {
    console.log(idx)
    fetch('/getDataReport', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json', 'responseType':'arraybuffer'},
      body: JSON.stringify({id: idx}),
    }).then(res => res.json()).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
  })
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
  }) 
  }
```

The above is triggered by onClick method, I get the id and put it in API body. When I give the id I want to make it download from db.

Flask code:

```
def getData():
   req = flask.request.get_json(force=True)
   id = req.get('id', None)
   report = Report.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
   return send_file(BytesIO(report.get_data()), attachment_filename=report.get_date()+'-report.pdf', as_attachment=True)
```

When I click download, Post request working fine actually. But I get "index.js:1437 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0" error and my response is undefined. I couldn't solve it. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance.

reactjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by looking at the line where you're attempting to deserialize the response as JSON:

```
.then(res => res.json())
```

Typically when fetching a file from an endpoint, the response is handled as a blob:

```
.then(res => res.blob()).then((blob) => { // do what you need to do })
```

[blob() MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob)

Once you've gotten the file, then you'll need a mechanism to force the browser to download the file. There are a few NPM packages that can help with this such as [downloadjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs) or you can roll your own.

[Another StackOverflow post on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545632/how-can-i-download-a-file-using-window-fetch)