# Set the filename for file download with use of Fetch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Tried out different solutions with headers, but can't set the filename of file downloaded:

NodeJs Server side (express):

```
res
.set('content-disposition', `attachment; filename="${filename}";  filename*=UTF-8''${encodeURI(filename)}`) // filename header
.type('.xlsx') // setting content-type to xlsx. based on file extention
wb.write(filename, res);
```

Client side (React + JS):

```
const options = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="filename.xlsx";'
      }
    };
    fetch("/api", options)
      .then( res => res.blob() )
      .then( blob => {
        var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.location.assign(file);
    });
```

I am receiving a proper file on client side, but the filename is like "93e43995-e4c2-4184-af62-a268d0b456e2.xlsx".

In the client console(network tab) I can see:

```
Request URL: blob:https://192.168.0.34:8443/e60d73fb-b423-4176-beb3-103028f8f225
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Length: 5823
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Provisional headers are shown
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

How can I set the headers to set the filename? Might be a wrong syntex somewhere? Please do not provide answers with JS a href object, like a.click. It's uncompatible to my case.

Update for Apoorva, thanks, looks great, but some error came up:

```
 Unexpected token, expected ","

  252 |              const filename =  response.headers.get('Content-Disposition').split('filename=')[1];
  253 |              return {response: res.blob(), filename: filename}})
> 254 |       .then( ({response, filename} => {
      |                                    ^
```

Could you please check once again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get it from the headers before converting the response into a blob.

```
const options = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="filename.xlsx";'
      }
    };
    fetch("/api", options)
      .then( res => {
             const filename =  res.headers.get('Content-Disposition').split('filename=')[1];
             return {response: res.blob(), filename: filename}})
      .then( ({response, filename}) => {
        var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
        window.location.assign(filename);
        console.log(filename)
    }).catch((e) => {console.log(e)})
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, helpful, but error came up. Please check question updated. I try myself to debug, but yours edits might be faster?

Comment: Check now, I have updated the answer, it was just a typo.

Comment: It says that - Line 252:32:  'response' is not defined  no-undef. In the row - const filename =  response.headers.get('Content-Disposition').split('filename=')[1]; I've tried to change response to res, but file not downloading.

Comment: Does it throw any error? Also, try checking the filename. It should work now. Put a debugger in then and check how it goes.

Comment: Trows: TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
    at Account2.js:255. 255 is: var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);

Comment: It is because of the response may be try this ` window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(response, {type: "provide type"}));`. May be the coming response is not blob, thats why try to put console to check the values of thes objects might help in debugging.

Comment: I've did a console.log(filename); Output is: "test.xlsx"; filename*=utf-8''test.xlsx; I will try your last comment. Throws: TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The object must have a callable @@iterator property.

Comment: Does the above thing helped?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233156/discussion-between-noszone-and-apoorva-chikara).

Comment: This causes my browser to navigate to http://localhost/"filename.xlsx"