# How do I save an image from an api response async and deepai

Tags: javascript, image, asynchronous

Im using deep AI API to make an image a cartoon

```
await deepai.renderResultIntoElement(result, document.getElementById('RES'));
})();
```

How can I save that file as well as it be displayed in a RES div?
it renderes fine even with updates!

UPDATE:

```
await deepai.renderResultIntoElement(result, document.getElementById('RES'));

let e=await fetch(result, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image',
    },
  });

let blob=await e.blob();

let url=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let a=document.createElement('a');
a.href=url;
a.download='cartoon.jpeg'; //here goes file name
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
sleep(100);
a.remove();

})()
```

I also tried let Blob=await response.blob();
that didnt work it just stopped it rendering!

Its nearly there its trying to download to a file but it is saying not correct format upon opening. any ideas?

Comment: Also tried saveAs(blob, "image.jpeg");

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get output file by sending GET request to url from result of callStandardApi method.
From that I get image response.
Then I download it as a file with hard coded name using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545632/how-can-i-download-a-file-using-window-fetch) solution.

```js
let e = await fetch(result.output_url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    },
  });

let blob = await e.blob();

let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
a.download = 'filename.jpeg'; //here goes file name
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
a.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, can i see the rest of it as im not using a get method im using blob from a ai i dont know how to send a file to that with a get method if you do please share the whole code on pastebin and share link :)

Comment: Iv updated the question as its sortof getting there maybe I hope. please check it out and tell me why it isnt quite working? I need to do the opposite to make a blob from something, i need to make a blob into a file that can be downloaded.

Comment: I tried saveAs(response, "image/jpeg", "image.jpeg");
And it didnt work any ideas?

Comment: It renders no problem it just dont save as a file ready for download or maybe even make it dl to client side without needing to dl first but i tried that and that idea failed.  what did i do wrong in my js any ideas please?

Comment: Check for updated code as it not visable but comments should still work wele fix it from comments https://pastebin.com/ZU36uFbV

Comment: You are trying to use blob() method on response. Isn't that impossible?

Comment: its only viewable for me, how annoying i need help with this and should be able to update as and when needed! let Blob=await response.blob(); didnt work it stopped it working at all!