# How can i use windows.fetch to fetch partially and download BIG file

Tags: javascript, html, webapi

I refered to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545632/how-can-i-download-a-file-using-window-fetch) and give me a hint how to automatically download a file

However, i have to problem.

1. the file i want to download is big, which is more than 7GB. i cannot save all the content in the memory and save to disk until the fetch finished.
2. i want to achieve `resume from breakpoint` feature for my downloading feature. which i have to use `range` header.
3. What's more. the file i download is a zip file. And i'm already able to extract it in memory. But how can i save the extracted files onto the disk in a location where the user want

How can i do it?

Comment: I think in general you're better off letting the browser take care of downloading large files natively unless there is some other reason you must stream the file through your javascript?

Comment: Yeah. What i want to do is download a zip file, extract it, and transfer it to a usb device. However i also want to backup the file onto the PC disk