# Extjs-When trying to download a zip file , zip file getting corrupted

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs5

when trying to get zip through postman we are getting zip file correctly , but when I'm trying to get using ajax call zip file I'm getting is corrupted . I used fetch function also but its not working

Comment: Hi and welcome on Stack Overflow. Please read guidelines how to ask a good question. Please share a code snippet, not an image. To your question, try it without Content Type json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download a file using window.fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545632/how-can-i-download-a-file-using-window-fetch)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)